# Quick introduction on how to use oracle xml data type

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

How do you work with the oracle XML data type?

*This question is intended to be [asked and answered](https://stackoverflow.com/faq) by me, just to share the information with others*

Comment: BAD JOB. Either get a blog, or make this community wiki!!!

Comment: How do you make it a "community wiki"? I was under the impression that doing this sort of thing was encouraged, as per the [stackoverflow faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq)

Comment: It should still be a question, though. "How do I work with" is a bit broad. +1 anyway.

Comment: You probably would not have gotten slammed for it without the statement of intention.

Comment: @astandar please read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down

Comment: @corydoras, I often ask questions that I end up answering, but this one is a little too vague, it should ask something specific

Answer (score 12):

The following sample SQL demonstrates how to insert, query and update database fields that contain the XMLTYPE data type:

```
-- Create a table that can store XML
create table sample_xml (id number, xml xmltype);

-- Insert some XML into the table
insert into sample_xml values (1, xmltype.createxml('<subject><name>test</name><list><li>a</li><li>b</li></list></subject>'));
insert into sample_xml values (2, xmltype.createxml('<subject><name>test</name><list><li>a</li></list></subject>'));

-- When doing a select, refer to table using the alias or getClobVal() will not work
select t.id, t.xml.getClobVal() from sample_xml t;

-- Update text of a single xml element
UPDATE sample_xml SET xml = UPDATEXML(xml, '/subject/name/text()','happy') WHERE id = 2;

-- Select out just the name for each row in the table using xpath
select id, extractvalue(xml, '/subject/name/text()') from sample_xml;

-- Doing an sample_xml, where the xpath string matches two elements, the text of both elements will be updated
UPDATE sample_xml SET xml = UPDATEXML(xml, '/subject/list/li/text()','one');
```